# Rack door open, or rack door closed

Tags: rack, physical-environment

In our 'server room' (not much more than a converted cupboard in reality) we have one struggling AC unit that is not man enough to cool the servers, which are housed in a full height rack.

The ambient temperature outside the room is lower than that inside the room, so I suppose opening the window is a decent idea (although this will allow dust ingress into the room), however, do I open the mesh door to the cabinet or leave it closed? To open the door you would think would let more of the hot air inside, out, however, would this lower the pressure of the cabinet? The cab is about 70% full, so there are still voids.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Is the cupboard locked, or can it be locked?

Comment: The room/cupboard is unlocked, we are a small company, and we trust our users to not go wandering in

Comment: What are the temperatures involved? Are your servers showing any distress?

Comment: Don't ever open the window. You do not want dust+moist air entering your servers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cooling for a small server room](http://serverfault.com/questions/139443/cooling-for-a-small-server-room)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please stop putting servers in broom cupboards.

1. Get 1U blanking plates to fill the holes up (or cardboard and foil tape).
2. Figure out a way to have hot air extracted from the back of the rack, and direct cold air from the AC unit to the front of the rack.
3. Spend some money on having the AC unit serviced and checked.
4. Spend even more money having a bigger, more powerful cooling system installed. **This is essential**
5. Get a bigger room for your servers.  [1]
6. Get a decent lock for the door.  I wouldn't trust your users, and neither should you.
7. Don't waste too much time worrying about the mesh door, it won't make a wit of difference (it's mesh).
8. Oh, and most importantly, treat this as a high priority task to improve the cooling in that room, as hardware **is** damaged by heat, and **will** fail as a result.

[1] A big problem you'll have is that the capacity for air in that room is small, hence once it's all hot, cooling capability is severely diminished.

Comment: You have to monitor the humidity level as well to avoid condensation.

Comment: -1 for your opening sentence, +1 for the rest of it. Sometimes space and budgetary constraints mean that those of us that are povo putting them in a cupboard is the only option against putting them in the middle of the office, or nowhere at all.

Comment: I'd sooner put servers in an acoustically damped rack, in the middle of the office, than in a hot, poorly ventilated broom cupboard in a corner.

Comment: @VashisthGoboodun I've frequently found that the AC unit acts a dehumidifier, condensing water out of the air as it goes over the chiller coils.  As long as the pump doesn't stop.. then water goes everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If the cabinet has fans, keeping the door closed ensures the hot air inside the cabinet leaves the cabinet more effectively. However opening or closing the door wont have any effect of the external AC unit.